# create a web service which uses Azure Functions (HTTP Trigger) to Post images to a Azure Blob Container and return the URI of the same image using SAS

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating a Azure web service in C# which will use Azure Functions to post an image(selfies) in a storage account using HTTP Trigger request. There will be two containers in the blob storage account, one for new user registration and another for existing user, when a new user takes a selfie it will post that image in the registry container and if it is a existing user, then the image will be posted to other container. After this, the web service will return the URI of the posted image using a Shared Access Signature.

I created a cloud solution in visual studio 2017 (.NET Framework) using the HTTP trigger request.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace KeolisKlockApp
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            if (name == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                name = data?.name;
            }

            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the return of the web service will be a URI of the posted image in azure blob which uses a shared access signature.

Comment: The image which is to be posted in the azure container will come from a Grabba Device as fingerprints, how can we match the fingerprints using image processing in Azure to find out if its a new image or an existing image??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please suggest an answer

Comment: @RahulDev, if you know the storage account name and account key, it's possible to return a url with sas token.

Comment: Yeah Ivan I know the storage account name and account key, can you please explain detail how can I return the URI with SAS token using a Azure Function? @Ivan Yang

Comment: @RahulDev, you can get the file in your function now and just don't know how to upload to blob storage and return an sas url? I'll post an answer later.

Comment: Please post a detailed answer as I'm new to azure functions and Blob Storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

local.settings.json(note, replace the value of AzureWebJobsStorage to your azure storage connection string):

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=your_storage_account;AccountKey=your_storage_account_key;BlobEndpoint=https://xx.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://xxx.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://xx.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://xx.file.core.windows.net/",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

For host.json, just leave it as default, like below:

```
{
    "version": "2.0"
}
```

---

Please use the code below for your testing purpose(It's just a simple code, and you can modify it to meet your need):

In visual studio, create a HttpTrigger azure function, then use the code below:

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string account_name = "your_storage_account_name";
            string account_key = "your_storage_account_key";
            string container_name = "your_container_name";
            string blob_name = name;


            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(account_name, account_key), true);
            CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference(container_name);
            CloudBlockBlob myblob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob_name);
            await myblob.UploadFromStreamAsync(req.Body);

            string blobSasUrl = GetBlobSasUri(blobContainer, blob_name, null);
            Console.WriteLine(blobSasUrl);

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }


        private static string GetBlobSasUri(CloudBlobContainer container, string blobName, string policyName = null)
        {
            string sasBlobToken;
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

            if (policyName == null)
            {
               SharedAccessBlobPolicy adHocSAS = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
                {
                    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
                    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create
                };

               sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(adHocSAS);

                Console.WriteLine("SAS for blob (ad hoc): {0}", sasBlobToken);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, policyName);

                Console.WriteLine("SAS for blob (stored access policy): {0}", sasBlobToken);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
            return blob.Uri + sasBlobToken;
        }
    }
```

Then click run button in visual studio to run the code locally. Here, I use postman for the test, you can see the test result as below: The blob sas url is generated, as well as the file is uploaded to the azure blob storage:

[image]

**If you don't know how to use postman to test, please follow the steps below:**

1.Click run button in visual studio, then wait for a while ,in the command prompt, there is a url which you need in postman:

[image]

2.Open postman, paste the url generated above in postman and select http method as POST, then in the Params section, fill in the key-value pair like name and it's value:

[image]

3.Then under the Body -> click the binary radio button -> click Select File, select a file you want to upload. At last, click Send button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Just one more query what should be the configuration of  host.json and localsetting.json file?

Comment: @RahulDev, please see the updated section in my answer. And if it works for you, please help mark it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: My postman is still sending the request and I can't find the picture on my azure portal.

Comment: I can't find any error as the Postman app doesn't stop sending the request. Can I have your email id I can send you a screenshot.

Comment: @Iavn Yang- Sent you a mail with screenshots please check.